# HTML - How do I make text in the body move onto the next line at some x-value along the page?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a simple html page that contains my projects and resume. I want to do something neat where the text is aligned to the right side of the page for certain elements of the page, and left for others. Rather than artificially installing 
 into the text that formats differently on mobile and desktops, how can I make it so that the text simply breaks into the next line at a certain point, rather than the edge of the screen? Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>xxx</title>
        <style>
            nav {border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);}
            body {padding: 5;margin: 20;background: #ffffff;}
            .slick {font-family: OCR A Std, monospace}
            .large_words {font-size: 120%;}
            .sub {font-size: 80%; text-align: right; width: 80%;}
            .grade_sub {font-size:70%;}
            .rightside {text-align: right;}
            .br {display: block;margin-bottom: 0em;}
            berkeley_cols {animation: color-change 3s infinite;}
            @keyframes color-change {0% {color: royalblue;} 50% { color: goldenrod;} 100% { color: royalblue;}}
            econ_cols {animation: money 5s infinite;}
            @keyframes money {0% {color: rgb(57, 199, 104);} 25% { color: rgb(6, 77, 30);} 
                                50% { color: rgb(0, 0, 0);} 75% { color: rgb(12, 77, 30);} 100% { color: rgb(57, 199, 104);}}
            data_science_cols {animation: datasci 3s infinite;}
            @keyframes datasci {0% {color: orange;} 50% { color: rgb(206, 11, 11);} 100% { color: orange;}}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slick"><h1>Welcome to my portfolio!</h1>
        <nav>
        </nav>
            <div class="large_words">
                <p align='left'>Hi, my name is xxx.<span class="br"></span> </div> This site showcases my projects and experience/education.</p>

            <span class="br"></span> 
            <p align="left">I graduated from 
                <a href="https://www.berkeley.edu/" target="_blank"><berkeley_cols><b>UC Berkeley</b></berkeley_cols></a>  
                with a B.A. in 
                <a href="https://www.econ.berkeley.edu/" target="_blank"><econ_cols><b>Economics</b></econ_cols></a>
                 and a minor in 
                <a href="https://data.berkeley.edu/academics/data-science-undergraduate-studies/data-science-minor" target="_blank"><data_science_cols><b>Data Science</b></data_science_cols></a>  in Summer 2022.
                </p>
            

            <h2 align="right">Applications</h2>

            <div class="rightside">
                <a href="xxx" target="_blank">Savings Rate Calculator</a>
            
            <div class="sub">
                This calculates a series of projected years needed from an investment as a function of a myriad of variables, 
                    <br> such as the interest rate, savings rate, annual income, a target $ amount and whether a recession has occured 
                    <br>(just decreases the investor's savings rate by an arbitrary value).<br>
                <a href="xxx">Here</a> is a 3 minute explanation of the application.
            </div>
            <div class="grade_sub">Grade: 10/10</div>
                <a href="xxx" target="_blank">State of the Union Address Word Analysis</a>
 
            <div class="sub">
                This allows for bag-of-words text analysis of the previous 20 State of the Union Addresses. 
                    <br>One can find the frequency of each word or phrase (up to four words), as well as plot the frequency 
                    <br> of any word throughout time.<br>
                <a href="xxx">Here</a> is a 4 minute explanation of the application.
            </div>
            <div class="grade_sub">Grade: 9.75/10</div>

            <h2>Data Analysis</h2>
            <a href="xxx", target="_blank">Cholangitis Study</a>
            <div class="sub">
                This report uses <b>R tidyverse and other libraries</b> to clean and explore a dataset coming from a randomized, <br>
                    double-blinded, placebo-controlled clinical trial ofthe immunosuppressive 
                    <br> drug D-penicillamine at the Mayo Clinic. Major points of exploration are linear and logistic 
                    <br>regression of the number of days a patient survives from the point of registration, and the status of a
                    <br> patient at the end of a study, respectively. This is supplemented by multivariate data visualization.
            </div>
            <div class="grade_sub">Grade: 78/80</div>
            <a href="xxx", target="_blank">Finding the best fictional NBA player</a>
            <div class="sub">
                This report uses <b>base Python, pandas and visualization packages</b> to find the objective
                    <br>best player from a fictional NBA timeline I started when I was 12 through 19 years old
                    <br> with the help of my imagination and NBA2K's MyLeague mode. Using a dataset of 87 notable players' statistics,
                    <br> I take as many factors into acocunt to come up with a ranking of each player.
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="slick"><p>Connect with me on <a href="xxx" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>!</p></div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

So imagine I text that just runs off onto the edge of the webpage before it breaks into a new line. How do I stop text that is aligned right at, say, the 50% mark of the webpage and make it break into the next line then?

Comment: your question is not very clear. can you provide an illustration or can you explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```css
.align-right{
  text-align: right; 
  width: 50%; 
  float: right; 
}
```

```html
<div class="align-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc egestas orci et lectus volutpat sodales. Integer cursus eros erat, et rhoncus mi convallis nec. </div>
```